# Python: Receiving (ValueError: {error} not in list) while {error} is in the list in any form

Tags: python, valueerror

I wanted to make a code which make a list containing numbers and upper cases
I am too lazy so I did this

```
import string
List1= [string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase]
```

And then one of my code will separate my input into every single unit, and then make them into the list number of the list {List1}

```
def get_ID(NotlistNum):
  num = []
  NotlistNum = NotlistNum.upper()
  for digits in NotlistNum:
    if digits == '.':
      DotPosit = len(num)
    else:
      num.append(List1.index(digits))
  return [num, DotPosit]
```

And then, run this

```
InputID=input(‘enter your ID: ‘)
InputID=InputID.upper()
print(get_ID(InputID))
```

But when I run it, this happened

```
enter your ID: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “main.py”, line 13, in <module>
    print(get_ID(InputID))
  File “main.py”, line 10, in get_ID
    num.append(List1.index(digits))
ValueError: ‘2’ is not in list
```

I then tried to make`List1= [‘0’, ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, ‘4’, ‘5’, ‘6’, ‘7’, ‘8’, ‘9’+string.ascii_uppercase` but same error occurs.
Anyone can help me find where the problem is?

Comment: Have you actually looked at `List1` after the first assignment (`List1= [string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase]`)? Is `'2'` in there? There's a string in there that has a '2' in it, but that's not the same. As for the second try, your code looks a bit odd with those word processor quotes `‘’` in there. Please share the code you were actually running to try that. It's still not what you want (`'9'+string.ascii_uppercase` doesn't do what you think it does), but it should definitely have `'2'` in there, unless those weird quotes are part of another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define List1 as

```
List1= [string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase]
```

your result will be
`['0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']`
it has one element and this element is this string.
So actually yes, List1 doesn't contain '2'.
If you want a proper list, try this:

```
list_ = list(string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase)
```

and you will have

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Update:
As you still have questions, here's how the code looks like now.
One thing remaining is that I don't know how you use DotPos - so I removed it, try adding it as you need.

```
import string

list_ = list(string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase)


def get_id(input_id: str):
    num = []
    for digit in input_id:
        num.append(list_.index(digit))
    return [num]


input_id = input('enter your ID: ').upper()

print(get_id(input_id))
```